# Salvar arquivo xml direto no cliente e não no servidor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho um arquivo XML, que ele pode ser criado, é alterado, e pode ser excluído, porém queria salvá-lo na máquina que o cliente está usando, e não no servidor, é possível ?

Assim é uma das formas que utilizo:

```
FileStream arquivo = new FileStream(item.Caminho + "\\NFSe-SUB" + numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + ".xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
```

Como publiquei no servidor, ele vai tentar procurar a pasta no servidor, e eu queria que ele acessasse a pasta configurado, que no caso está na máquina que o cliente está acessando `E:\XML`

Comment: Acho que não tem como fazer isso com 1 página web normal, o cliente teria que fazer o upload dos XML, pode até fazer em lote, mas vai ter que fazer.
Eu trabalho com NFSe, NFe, CTe, etc e sei o que está tentando fazer, mas não vai ser possível a menos que esteja usando uma api tipo Electron para a aplicação rodar localmente

Comment: Você quer manipular (ler, criar, editar, excluir) o arquivo no cliente?

Comment: @Reiksiel no caso o usuário pode optar por salvar tanto no servidor como na máquina dele.

Comment: @LINQ isso, como posso fazer?

Comment: @marianac_costa Não pode.

Comment: @LINQ não existe nenhuma maneira de contornar a situação ?

Comment: @marianac_costa, eu te dei a opção de rodar localmente.Todo acesso que o html/javascript tem há máquina é feito pelo browser que interpreta a linguagem e fornece uma interface para que a esta tenha acesso há alguns dados do sistema. Isso que você quer causaria uma falha de segurança tremenda.

Comment: @Reiksiel entendi, no caso eu compartilhei a pasta, e coloquei para salvar nela, assim dá certo, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida com você, já que você tem experiências com Notas eletrônicas, eu tenho o certificado, e ele vai ficar na máquina do usuário e não no servidor, como ele pode reconhecer?  Eu busco assim `var store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);` direto na minha máquina ele dá certo, mas ao colocar no servidor, ele dá erro.

Comment: @marianac_costa, acho que esse não é o local, mas caso queira tirar dúvidas entre em contato com o meu email: rickphilippe@gmail.com

Sobre o certificado: o certificado precisa ser instalado no servidor para que esse tenha acesso, o cliente vai ter que te passar o certificado uma vez pelo menos.